# False when check for upper later in python

Tags: python, string

I need to check if the first letter of a list is upper. For that I wrote this simple code, where obviasly my word "Try" starts with capital "T":

```
h=[]
h.append("Try")
a = str(h[0])
print(a)
print(a.isupper())
```

BUT when I print a.isupper I get always False. Should I convert the variable in something, or it should be str object? How can I solve this problem

Comment: Currently you check if whole string is upper but you must only take the first letter.

Comment: I guess you read somewhere that you had to use `a[0].isupper()` but then you confused it with `h[0]` which takes the first string from the list, not the first character from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need the list. Just do:

```
a= "Try"
print(a[0].isupper())
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the whole string to be capital, that's why it's `False`.

When you do `print(a[0].isupper())`, it checks if the whole string(`Try` in your case) is capital. Hence, it returns False.

You want to check just the first letter of the string, so do this instead:

```
In [615]: print(a[0].isupper())                                                                                                                                                                             
True
```

Where `a[0]` gives you `T`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `h[0]` which gives `"Try"`, and when you check for `a.isupper()`
It has both lower case and upper case , please check for `a[0]` , then you get true if the first letter is capital